# If I change my name in the UK, and visit the US again on an ESTA, will I have issues?

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, esta

I'm currently known as John A, my passport and current ESTA is in this name. My ESTA is due to expire this month.

I'm back in the UK now and I plan to change my name to John B. I will get a new passport and ESTA under the name John B.

What kind of issues am I likely to get next time I visit the US?

Will I have to have fingerprints and my photograph redone? Will this cause issues at the kiosk when my fingerprints and face match a different name?

If I am likely to incur issues, what documentation should I take with me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You won't have any issues, but you will need to get a new ESTA once you have your new passport.

To quote from the [official source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/~/apply-or-change-information-in-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization):

> If you obtain a new passport or change your name, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of the VWP eligibility questions changes. The associated fee of $14 will be charged for each new application.